# Ckan harvester certification error

Tags: ckan, harvest

I installed ckan in my docker container.I have also proxy setttings.I can create harvest job in web UI but I cannot collect datasets from websites like that demo.ckan.org.In comamnd line I send a curl request and It gives certification error.How do I handle it? In my network,I can perform harvest process properly. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do provide the error messages

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the client (CKAN Harvester) is using an out of date list of certification authorities (CAs). [CKAN Harvester](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/blob/master/ckanext/harvest/harvesters/ckanharvester.py) hasn't been upgraded from 'urllib2' to 'requests' yet, which would be the best way to fix this. As a potential beneficiary of so many other contributions to this open source project, is little improvement something you're able to contribute?